# How to load through js files sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three games that I want to load on a website, in 3 separate js files. They are all contained within a function in that file to start the game. My code right now is

```
    //jQuery to start a game once the
    $(document).ready(() => {
        //When the logo image is clicked
        $("#logo").click(() => {
            //Get the archery game
            $.getScript('archery.js', () => {
                //Start it (call the start game function)
                startArchGame();
                //Remove the image from the HTML doc
                $("#logo").remove();
            });
        })
    })
```

How can I load the next file when the game is done?

Comment: It may help to create a function that ends the current game and goes on to a different game that has been selected.

Comment: @Kenzoid thanks for that, don’t know why I didn’t consider that 